# Increase height of TextView on runtime

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` and I want to increase its height on runtime.

I have used `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but it did not gave me the desired result.

I'm using a Relative Layout.

i get text through edittext and i want to set it on textview.
when i do this it shows only one line, and when i click on edittext it get expanded and full message is shown.

Comment: Do you mean you want the textbox to expand as the user types into it, so that it's always as big as its content?

Answer (score 1):

> Add in Oncreate method of your
>   Activity class,
>
> ((TextView)
>   findViewById(R.id.YOURTEXTVIEWIDHERE)).setHeight(IntegerValuePixels);

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell without more details - but do you really need to change it on runtime? because obviously you're not happy with the height at startup.

have you thought about using `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, eventually in combination with the `android:minHeight` attribute of other components?